# What is the difference between 0d and (double)0?

Tags: c#

Example 1:

```
if ((Value ?? 0d) <= 0d)
{
    //some code
}
```

Example 2:

```
if ((Value ?? (double)0) <= (double)0)
{
    //some code
}
```

What is the difference between these two? and which one is better to use?

Comment: FWIW: `(Value ?? 0) <= 0` (hurrah type promotions)

Comment: MSDN says: By default, a real numeric literal on the right side of the assignment operator is treated as double. However, if you want an integer number to be treated as double, use the suffix d or D.

Comment: Actually both are compiled to the same code, there is no runtime casting in the second case.

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov, that would be courtesy of compiler optimisation I would say so there may well be a difference in Debug but not Release. Regardless, casting a literal is of one type to another when you could just use a literal of the type you wanted in the first place is complicating code unnecessarily.

Comment: @jmcilhinney In this case it will be optimized in Debug mode too. But I agree with you that the first method is the proper one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both code snippets are equivalent, as the type-cast will be performed by the compiler at compile-time, and the result treated as a constant. Note that this is standard behaviour, not just a compiler optimization; otherwise, you would not be able to use casts for constants:

```
    const double d1 = (double)0;          // allowed
    const double d2 = Math.Pow(2, 4);     // error: "The expression being assigned to 'd2' must be constant"
```

Specifying the proper literal suffix is nonetheless preferred as it keeps your code concise. Another popular convention for specifying doubles is to append `.0`:

```
if ((Value ?? 0.0) <= 0.0)
```

Answer (score 3):

The first one is better.

Second one makes the cast happen at runtime. First one declares constant as double right away.